# Update TestCafe script execution status ( passed / failed ) in TestRail

Tags: automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe, testrail

I am trying to integrate TestRail with TestCafe in order to update the test script execution status on TestRail. I followed the below link but did not succeed 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html-testrail
tried with below one, but not succeeded.

test('<< Group Name>> | << Test Name >> | << Testrail Case_ID >> ', async t => { .... });

Can you please help me with this?

note: my question is same as : https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/is-there-anyway-to-post-test-results-from-a-run/377

Answer (score 3):

As I understand from the https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/is-there-anyway-to-post-test-results-from-a-run/377 thread, it's enough to send some requests to TestRail API to solve the issue.

I took a look at `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` and, at first glance, it should send such requests.

I would recommend you review code of `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` and debug it to find the cause why it does not work. I suggest you start from these reporter methods: 
https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/extending-testcafe/reporter-plugin/reporter-methods.html.

Since `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` is not an official TestCafe reporter, we cannot provide any detailed information about it. I cannot find the repository of `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` on GitHub, but it still exists on npm, so probably you can contact the author of this module.

Comment: Thanks Alex, As you mentioned i did not find testcafe-reporter-html-testrail repository hence i need help to exact method with parameter info to send request to TestRail API. As you looked at testcafe-reporter-html-testrail , do you have any idea how TESTRAIL-HOST, TESTRAIL_USER, TESTRAIL_PASS, PROJECT_NAME would be passed through.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the TestRail API, so I'm not sure how those parameters are passed through.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running tests using the TestCafe CLI, then this is how you would pass the required testrail environment variables required for the `testcafe-reporter-html-testrail` plugin to work:

```
TESTRAIL_ENABLE=true TESTRAIL_HOST=http://example.net/ TESTRAIL_USER=abc@example.net TESTRAIL_PASS=password PROJECT_NAME='ABC' testcafe chrome test.js
```